# The correct regular expression to find a partial string

Tags: regex

I have a document where several times a text structure like this appear:

```
/* 6 */  some text /* 123 */ some text /* 12 */
```

I want to search for all the occurrences of the structure `/*???*/` using regular expressions.

So far i got `/\*??` but is not matching the whole text.

Comment: What text editor or programming language do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
/\*\s+\d+\s+\*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This will have 3 matching groups: 6, 123 and 12 . I tested it using [this regex tester](http://regexhero.net/tester/)

```
/\*.*?\*/
```